# Last Of Type / Last Child with Classes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to select the 2nd `warranty-box` class with CSS alone? I've tried combinations of `last-of-type` and `last-child`, but I haven't come up with anything that works.

From what I can tell, the "row" and "columns" wrappers break the sibling style relationships `last-of-type` and `last-child` depend on.

I've tried combinations of like `.warranty .warranty-box:last-of-type` but I seem to only be selecting either both of them or neither.

My brain hurts at this point.

```html
<section class="warranty">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-centered medium-10 large-8 columns">
      <div class="warranty-box">
        <h2>All New Homes Include</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>7-Year Warranty*</li>
          <li>107 Point Final Inspection</li>
          <li>CSP (Customer Service Program)</li>
          <li>Delivery Anywhere in Ohio**</li>
          <li>Base Set Installation</li>
          <li>Roll on/Beams-Guide System Set</li>
          <li>Central Air Conditioning</li>
          <li>Gutters and Downspouts</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="medium-centered medium-10 large-6 columns">
      <div class="warranty-box">
        <h2>Pre-Existing Homes Include</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>1, 2, or 3-Year Warranty on Qualified Homes*</li>
          <li>107 Point Final Inspection</li>
          <li>Central Air Conditioning</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the `first-`, `nth-`, and `last-` pseudo-selectors are relative to the element's parent, which in this case are the `.columns` divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the last element by type and then target the class.

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/2362mjox/1/

```
.warranty > div:last-of-type .warranty-box {
  background: red;
}
```

the code above will look for the last midiate div child of `warranty`

Comment: Thank you! I found it incredibly hard to find any references without just the _most basic_ of examples!

Comment: Note that this won't work if OP adds another div with .warranty-box after the 2nd one; in that instance it will select the recently-added 3rd div instead. For selecting a specific number element it is better to use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` instead, so that future modifications after the fact are less likely to break.